# Archimedean property with equivalent properties.

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}.$ I found that the following properties are equivalent to the Archimedean property of reals.

$(1)$ The set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above.

$(2)$ If $x>0,$ there exist $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}<x.$

$(3)$ If $x>0,$ then there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n-1\leq x\leq n.$

$(4)$ The set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

$(5)$ Inf $\{ \frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}=0.$

$(6)$ $\cap_{n}(0,1/n)=0.$

Now i like to add more property in above equivalent properties. Please try to add as much as possible. Using $(4)$ we can prove irrationals are also dense in $\mathbb{R},$ but i don't know about converse. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we add denseness of irrationals?

Comment: whats more properties we can add?